ETW ProcessStart event callback is not called within service
I'm writing a windows service which needs to read ProcessStart events using ETW, when I run the service it manages to subscribe to the event using the Kernel provider without an exception, but it doesn't receive the events (i.e. the callback is not called).
I have created a mimic program which does the same and ran it as system via psexec and it does work there.
The minimal reproducible code is simply adding the following code in the OnStart of the service:
_ = session.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.Process);

if (!(TraceEventSession.IsElevated() ?? false))
{
    Log("To turn on ETW events you need to be Administrator, please run from an Admin process.");
} else
{
    Log("Process is elevated");
}



session.Source.Kernel.ProcessStart += (ProcessTraceData data) => {
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    try
    {
        Log($"Process Opened: {data.ProcessID}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log($"Process Error: {ex}");
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
    }
};

And that is the OnContinue:
 _ = session.Source.Process();


When you let run your code not as a service it works? Under which user account are you running?
